# Javascript engine can not be found - scripting for the Java platform

Tags: java, javascript, scripting

Recently some of my users have been reporting problems with NullPointers. Thanks to one of them, I have managed to find out that my application can't find the Javascript engine that should theoretically come with the JRE (most of them have the JDK anyway).

How can they manually install the scripting engine?

Thanks in advance...

P.S. Most of these people have OpenJDK. However, this doesn't happen to me (I am also an OpenJDK user)...
EDIT: They have at least version 1.5, most of them have 1.6.

Comment: What JDK version do they have?  The Rhino stuff has only been there since 1.5.

Comment: They have 1.5 or up, most of them have 1.6.

Comment: Ah well oops - it's 1.6, not 1.5, that introduced Rhino.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [JSR 270](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=270) (the Java 6 SE spec):

> There will be no requirement that any
>   particular scripting language be
>   supported by the platform;
>   implementors may choose to include
>   support for the scripting language(s)
>   of their choice as they see ﬁt.

So, it is conceivable that there are JREs out there without JavaScript support. There may also be variations in engine names, language names and versions bundled. *"JavaScript" is an Oracle trademark so some vendors might be reluctant to use it as an identifier string.*

Comment: @nickguletskii - you should be able to just add Rhino and the appropriate JSR 223 engine to the classpath. There used to be a set of engine binaries at http://java.net/projects/scripting/ but they seem to have disappeared since the Oracle takeover. Still, the sources still seem to be there.

Answer (score 1):

The [Rhino engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) has only been bundled with Java [since Java 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/). Thus, your Java 5/1.5 users won't have it preinstalled.

That said, you can get Rhino, the Javascript engine, manually from [Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/download.html)'s site, since the engine itself does work with Java 5. However, you will have to use [Rhino's API](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/), rather than working with Java's [ScriptEngine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) interface.

Comment: @nickguletskii and are Java 1.6 users reporting this error? An abridged stack trace and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the problem code would be very helpful for diagnosing your issue :-)

Comment: Yes, they are. A stack trace is not useful - it will only show that the error is on the line where it first references the script engine, and that the script engine is null. An example: http://pastebin.com/iQEAwE3A