# Using Lisp or Scheme for runtime configuration of Java programs

Tags: java, lisp, scheme

I have now seen several projects ending at a point where the actual configuration depended on things only available at run-time.

The typical way to configure a Java program is to read one or more property files according to some application specific rules and then take action depending on their values.  At one point or another this breaks down and you need actual program logic in your configuration which then can be indicated with a flag and adding code to your application which then handles the flag.

I was wondering if a tiny Lisp configuration reader module might be a better option, where the file to be read is not a property file but a Lisp program which is then eval'ed to create a final datastructure representing the configuration.  A minimal set of functions in the runtime library would then allow string manipulation and perhaps even calling into the JVM.  Just think of "construct an URL based on the current hostname".

I am *not* interested in a full Lisp engine with bells and whistles but just a small library for this purpose which can be enclosed in even small programs without a large jar containing the Lisp engine.

So does such a library exist?

- Small size
- Just need read file + eval and the ability to read the resulting data structure from the main Java program
- A small Lisp runtime library
- Speed is of lesser importance.
- Actively maintained.

Suggestions?

---

Edit 2012-01-20: I initially found all the candidates undesirable, but have decided to use this as a Maven exercise on the side with [the 1998 jscheme 1.4 release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161027/53897).  Project at https://github.com/ravn/jscheme-1998

---

Edit 2012-12-11: It turned out that the *integration* layer between the program being interpreted in Scheme and the host Java program was more important that I originally thought, and that I needed in a project to be able to provide classes with JAX-WS annotaions at runtime, which I could not do with JScheme but I could do with Groovy.  The idea of a small configuration library which allows code snippets in the libraries is still valid, but I ended up needing more for it to be useful.

Comment: have you thought of using [JavaScript](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/) with JSON? That'd give you scripting and [binding](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) JSON to Java types would be relatively easy. _Be aware that there are [pitfalls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089773) if you don't know your target JRE._

Comment: @McDowell, I've thought of JavaScript as is it is provided by default in many JSR-233 capable JVM's, but as you say it is not available universally so I need to carry it along.  I believe a tiny Lisp evaluator should be smaller.

Comment: @McDowell My target JVM has since gotten a JavaScript engine enclosed, so this is not a problem anymore.  I now, however, have another job :)

Answer (score 8):

I know you want a small size and runtime. Scheme is the usual choice for easy embedding, and would be my first choice. But I have no information on that field, though. My second choice is *[Clojure](http://clojure.org)*:

- Not that small; the jar is ~3 MB
- Overkill for a simple config reading, but the extra features can be safely ignored
- ~ Easy to call from Java: [Calling clojure from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java)
- Full, excellent access to JVM
- Might invoke a small extra to the startup, which can be too much (see below)
- Now that I tried replicating the example's functionality with Clojure, I feel that Clojure isn't well suited for these kind of scripts (rc, etc). Clojure 1.3 will address some of that startup penalty but I don't know the magnitude of speed improvements coming

*A respective code with using Clojure*:

```
import clojure.lang.RT;
import clojure.lang.Var;
import clojure.lang.Compiler;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ClojTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Compiler.load(new FileReader("hello.clj"));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { return; }

        System.out.println("Message: '"+ RT.var("user", "msg").get() +"'");

        // Values
        int answer = (Integer) RT.var("user", "answer").get();

        // Function calls
        System.out.println(RT.var("user", "countdown").invoke(42));
    }
}
```

with `hello.clj` being:

```
(ns user)
(defn countdown [n]
  (reduce + (range 1 (inc n))))

(def msg "Hello from Clojure!")
(def answer (countdown 42))
```

Running `time java ClojTest` for a while yields in an average of **0.75 seconds.** Clojure compiling the script has quite a penalty!

Comment: 3 Mb is _way_ over what I think a "read configuration files" module should be.  I've heard much good about Clojure though.

Answer (score 8):

Good, much smaller solution is an embedded Scheme for Java. Out of many implementations, I found and tested [JScheme](http://jscheme.sourceforge.net/jscheme/main.html). (API looks okay: http://jscheme.sourceforge.net/jscheme/doc/api/index.html)

A simple main program in Java:

```
import jscheme.JScheme;
import jscheme.SchemeException;
import java.io.*;
public class SchemeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JScheme js = null;
        try {
            js = new JScheme();
            js.load(new FileReader("config.scm"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { return; }

        System.out.println("Message: '" + js.eval("msg") + "'");

        // Values
        int answer = (Integer) js.eval("answer");

        // Function calls
        System.out.println(js.call("countdown", 42));
    }
}
```

And an example `config.scm`:

```
(define (countdown x)
  (define (loop x acc)
    (if (= x 0)
      acc
      (loop (- x 1) (+ acc x))))
  (loop x 0))

;;; config variables
(define msg "Hello from JScheme!")
;; tail calls are optimized as required
(define answer (countdown 42))
```

The scheme is being interpreted at startup every time, so this is good choice for configurations.  Advantages to JScheme include:

- good JVM integration
- apparently a complete Scheme implementation
- smallish size (572 kB)
- fast, somewhat easily called from Java

**Benchmark update**: this code runs in **0.13 seconds** time. Compared to the Clojure version's time this is pretty fast.

Comment: I'll have a look at the scheme-lite thing.

Comment: I've had a look at the 7.2 download and I cannot find the lite jar you are talking about.  Where did you see it?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: it came with the package in Gentoo. I'm sorry--I should have checked it earlier because it's nothing. :(

Comment: It turned out that jschemelite.jar only contains build/SchemeLite.java which just downloads the jscheme.jar file from sourceforge in an URLClassLoader and invokes the main method.  Not quite what I had in mind.

Comment: Also it looks like development activity is _very_ low :-(

Answer (score 6):

Try [SISC](http://sisc-scheme.org/), it is a reasonably small (300kb jar) Scheme implementation with no bells and whistles. Glueing it with Java is trivial, and an execution speed is quite impressive for a pure interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

Clojure is excellent, it is embeddable and has very good interoperability for calling Java libraries. However it is not particularly small (you get a full compiler and quite a decent runtime library included). Still worth considering if you have a broader requirement for this kind of functionality - I've found Clojure to work as an excellent dynamic "glue" for Java code.

Otherwise, your best bet is probably a tiny embedded Scheme interpreter.

It may be possible to use the early (1998) version of JScheme at this link, which is only about a 30k jar file:
http://norvig.com/jscheme.html

Otherwise, it's probably possible to write something even more minimal in a few hundred lines of Java.... it's probably only a weekend project considering how small the core of Scheme is. The following page is quite interesting if you want to write a mini-interpreter for Scheme:
http://archives.evergreen.edu/webpages/curricular/2000-2001/fofc00/eval.html

Comment: I'd prefer to use a maintained library for this, instead of hacking stuff together mysefl.

Comment: Updated - you may want the 1998 version of JScheme perhaps?

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have a look at 1998 JScheme.