# How to use ScriptEngine in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, java-8, scalatest, nashorn

The following test should pass, but it doesn't

```
class EngineTest extends FunSuite {

  test("engine should not be null") {
    val manager: ScriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager
    val engine: ScriptEngine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn")
    assert(engine != null)
  }
}
```

The `manager.getEngineFactories()` seems to be empty. Why? How to init the context?

Comment: Made the Test pass in the IDE but not sbt from shell. Wonder what is different.

Comment: the classpath is most likely the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10054252/1296806 for distro-dependence of rhino support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What versions are you using?  This is sbt .13.

```
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import javax.script._
import javax.script._

scala> new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
res0: javax.script.ScriptEngine = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain@7078c799

scala> new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino")
res1: javax.script.ScriptEngine = com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine@5c854934

scala> new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineFactories
res2: java.util.List[javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory] = [com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngineFactory@454ee4c0, scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Factory@354e3bce]
```

Wait, you asked about test context --

Well, before I lost interest in decoding more sbt, adding to libraryDependencies:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value % "test",
```

enables locating the Scala script engine:

```
  @Test def engines: Unit = {
    import javax.script._
    val all = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineFactories
    Console println s"Found ${all.size}: $all"
    assert(all.size > 0)
  }
```

No doubt there's a simple way to add runtime:full-classpath to test:full-classpath directly. Because it's the simple build tool, right?

For Nashorn on Java 8, note the location:

```
> set fullClasspath in Test += Attributed.blank(file(s"${util.Properties.javaHome}/lib/ext/nashorn.jar"))
[info] Defining test:fullClasspath
[info] The new value will be used by test:console, test:executeTests and 5 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to goofy (in build file:/home/apm/goofy/)
> test
Found 1: [jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory@7fa2239d]
[info] Passed: Total 10, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 10
```

Update:  https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1214

Also [I guess it's still considered black art](https://github.com/tgambet/js-engine/commit/167412fc7a8a5639889429c555132d0a58d3256d):

```
// Somehow required to get a js engine in tests (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1214)

fork in Test := true
```

Comment: I was just guessing: `> set (fullClasspath in Test) ++= (fullClasspath in Runtime).value` but those are just deps.

Answer (score 5):

You need to explicitly pass in a ClassLoader to the ScriptEngineManager constructor.  If you don't then it uses `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` which is set to something weird when running under SBT.  We just pass in `null` in our code to get it to work.  You can also pass in `getClass.getClassLoader`:

```
class EngineTest extends FunSuite {
  test("engine should not be null - null classloader") {
    val manager: ScriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager(null)
    val engine: ScriptEngine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn")
    assert(engine != null)
  }

  test("engine should not be null - getClass.getClassLoader classloader") {
    val manager: ScriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val engine: ScriptEngine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn")
    assert(engine != null)
  }
}
```

Both of those tests pass for me:

```
[info] EngineTest:
[info] - engine should not be null - null classloader
[info] - engine should not be null - getClass.getClassLoader classloader
[info] Run completed in 186 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I had to change was to use:

`fork in Test := true`

as mentioned above - from here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1214