# Problems generating ant scripts for java when linking to Rhino

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, rhino

When I try to build my project using ant, I get:
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/org/mozilla/javascript/internal/Scriptable"

This stems from my usage of Rhino (the bundled java-script that comes with Oracle JDK)

- When I build the project with eclipse, everything works fine.
- The ant file I am using was generated by eclipse, and works fine except for the java-script dependencies.
- These dependencies are located in the RT.jar that comes with the oracle JDK.
- I have tried both jdk6_0_u41  and jdk7, and both give the same results: success in eclipse, fail with ant.
- I have tried to build on both ubuntu 10, and 12

I have seen two other suggestions which seem unacceptible to me:

- One thread suggested copying RT.jar into the project lib directory. (RT is entire java runtime! )
- Another thread suggested that I shouldn't  use:sun/org/mozilla/javascript/internal. But since I am doing advanced manipulation (Calling object methods, registering callbacks, etc) I see no alternative to using the sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal family of classes.

Comment: Is Ant using the same build classpath? Consider using your own Rhino implementation. Java makes [no guarantees](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089959/304) about what scripting engines ship with different versions/implementations.

Comment: The Ant file was generated by eclipse, so I assume it is using the same classpath. Besides that, I only have one jdk installed on the build machine (I went to great lengths to make sure openJDK wasn't installed). As such is it even possible for the java compiler link  without the RT.jar supplied with the JDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment from Oracle's site:

> Users should not write code that depends on internal JDK implementation classes. Such classes are internal implementation
>   details of the JDK and subject to change without notice.
>
> This is not a compiler issue. javac is behaving correctly, according
>   to the information provided in ct.sym.
>
> The issue belongs with those who decide what should be available with
>   (and what should be hidden by) ct.sym

You may suggest to include [Rhino's jar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Download_Rhino) to your project and repoint it on original's Rhino classes where 'internals' are not hidden from users