# In Java, how to dynamically create a relational expression, execute it and get the final boolean result

Tags: java

I've 2 fields in DB e.g. `senti_op` and `senti_score` both of which are Strings . `senti_score` contains strings of value `Double` i.e `25.00`, `30.50` etc whereas the `senti_op` contains strings of relational operators like `>=`, `>`, `<` etc.

In Java, I want to do like this:

- for `senti_op` `>=` , I want the logical expression as: `if ("some double value" >= senti_score)`
- for `<` , I want `if ("some double value" < senti_score)`

I'm trying to form these relational expression and get their `boolean` result to be used later by other part of the code.

Please provide compilable Java example code. I'm trying to avoid writing lots of if-else statements using string comparison for each operator and evaluate the values and looking for small and working solution.

I'm pretty new to such things and would appreciate all your help.

Comment: It's not *that* many combinations. I wouldn't say it's "lots of if-else statements."

Comment: Why are you storing numerical values as strings to start with?

Comment: Thats a design constraint, which I don't have control over.

Comment: Is there a way I can form a complete expression, using Strings and then say expression.execute() and it'll give the boolean result? something similar to that.

Comment: Sure, but you'll just end up parsing out the values and operator from the string and then use an if-else chain to evaluate it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class SimpleTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            String exp = "some double value"+ senti_op +senti_score;
            try {
                System.out.println(engine.eval(exp));
            } catch (ScriptException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick solution. one quick Qs: do I need to add separate lib for ScriptEngine?

Comment: The JS scripting engine might not be present on all platforms. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089959/467874

Answer (score 1):

Not tested (with some [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) annotations and some [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/))

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
private static enum Operation {
    LESS_OR_EQUAL("<="), GREATER_OR_EQUAL(">="), 
    GREATER(">"), LESS("<"), EQUALS("=");

    @Getter
    final String operation;

    public static Operation parse(final String val) {
        for(final Operation pop : values()) {
            if (pop.getOperation().equals(val)) {
                return pop;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean handleOperation(final String senti_score, final String senti_op, final Double someDoubleVal) {
    // parse the double
    final Double sentiScore = Doubles.tryParse(senti_score);
    // parse the operation using Operation enum
    final Operation sentiOp = Operation.parse(senti_op);

    // TODO: checks for nullity on both parsed value

    // use a switch to compute result
    switch (sentiOp) {
    case LESS_OR_EQUAL:
        return someDoubleVal.compareTo(sentiScore) <= 1; 
    case GREATER_OR_EQUAL:
        return someDoubleVal.compareTo(sentiScore) >= 1;
    case LESS:
        return someDoubleVal.compareTo(sentiScore) < 1;
    case GREATER:
        return someDoubleVal.compareTo(sentiScore) > 1;
    case EQUAL:
        return someDoubleVal.compareTo(sentiScore) == 0;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled op:" + senti_op);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7, you can avoid writing the if-else chain using the switch statement on String.

You should also look into [floating point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de). It does not always behave as one could expect.

```
public class SentiEvaluator {

    public boolean evaluate(String sentiOp, String sentiScore, double otherValue) {
        if (sentiOp == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator must be specified.");
        }
        if (sentiScore == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Score must be specified.");
        }

        double score = Double.parseDouble(sentiScore);
        return evaluateJava7(score, sentiOp, otherValue);
    }

    private boolean evaluateJava7(double leftOp, String operator, double rightOp) {
        switch (operator) {
            case "=": return leftOp == rightOp;
            case ">": return leftOp > rightOp;
            case ">=": return leftOp >= rightOp;
            case "<": return leftOp < rightOp;
            case "<=": return leftOp <= rightOp;
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator " + operator);
        }
    }

}
```