# How to resolve No ScriptEngine found for language js?

Tags: java, spring, maven, scriptengine

I'm sure this issue is resolved somewhere online, but I haven't been able to find it. I read over this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013310/java-scriptengine-supported-languages), but I'm not sure how to go about adding in a new `ScriptEngine` for Javascript.

I wrote a Java application that, to my knowledge, does not use JavaScript anywhere in it. This is a Spring application that uses Maven, but following a `mvn clean package` and successful build, running `java -jar app/target/app-X.X.X-SNAPSHOT.jar` results in `main ERROR No ScriptEngine found for language js`.

Would anyone happen to know why a project that does not use JS, throw an error in regards to it? Is there any known way (or even documentation anywere) to resolve it or other issues related to `ScriptEngine`?

```
2020-12-10 20:43:50,584 main ERROR No ScriptEngine found for language js. Available languages are: 
2020-12-10 20:43:50,641 main ERROR Unable to create file /data/logs/out/out.log java.io.IOException: Could not create directory /data/logs/out
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.mkdir(FileUtils.java:127)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:144)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:650)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:631)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1002)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:934)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:288)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:579)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:668)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:196)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.Application.main(Application.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

Comment: Include your entire stack trace and the actual behavior: Does that `ERROR` output actually cause any problems with your program, or is it just a diagnostic?

Comment: It has been added.

Comment: Again, does your application fail to start or otherwise malfunction? (Note, by the way, that log4j is obsolete, and in a new application you should be using either slf4j, which is the Boot default, or log4j2.)

Answer (score 1):

Since your application is failing in Log4J I assume you used JavaScript in Log4J configuration.

The JavaScript engine was removed in JDK 15. See [JEP 372: Remove the Nashorn JavaScript Engine](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372)

A possible solution is to use Groovy instead.