# scripting in Java via javax.script: cannot retrieve ScriptEngine for Python

Tags: java, python, javax.script

I have a little maven project to learn about scripting in Java using javax.script API, namely JavaScript and Python. While JavaScript works well, like e.g. in this method

```
@Test
public void TestPrintHelloWorldJs() throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    
    engine.eval("print('Hello, World')"); // works
}
```

I cannot get python running at all because the returned engine is always null:

```
@Test
public void TestPrintHelloWorldPy() throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("python"); // returns null !!!
    engine = factory.getEngineByName("jython"); // still returns null !!!

    engine.eval("print('Hello, World')"); // NullPointerException here
}
```

**Any ideas what I can do to make it work?**

---

Here are the relevant parts of my pom:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>15</maven.compiler.release> <!-- Java 15 -->
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId> <!-- for testing -->
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
        <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId> <!-- for javascript-->
        <version>15.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.python</groupId>
        <artifactId>jython</artifactId> <!-- for python -->
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I use the method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38039047/5333340 in order to print out available engines, and the output I get is:

```
ScriptEngineFactory Info
    Script Engine: OpenJDK Nashorn (15.3)
    Engine Alias: nashorn
    Engine Alias: Nashorn
    Engine Alias: js
    Engine Alias: JS
    Engine Alias: JavaScript
    Engine Alias: javascript
    Engine Alias: ECMAScript
    Engine Alias: ecmascript
    Language: ECMAScript (ECMA - 262 Edition 5.1)
ScriptEngineFactory Info
    Script Engine: jython (2.7.2)
    Engine Alias: python
    Engine Alias: jython
    Language: python (2.7)
```

So the engine IS found. But why can't I get it? I double-checked that the arguments in `getEngineByName` have no typos.

I even installed python 2.7 on my computer (although I don't think this is actually necessary; the implementation should be inside the jython package), but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Seems I wasn't using the right dependency...

I replaced

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

by

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython-standalone -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and that's it.