# Checking if a function exists within java ScriptEngine

Tags: java

Is there a neat way to check if a function exists in a java ScriptEngine. For example I create a ScriptEngine:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval("function test(){"
            + "return ~-1;"
            + "}"
            + "test1 = 10;");
```

My current way of checking if a function exists is to do something like this:

```
engine.get("test").getClass().getName().equals("sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction")
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do it with `instanceof` the problem I'm having at the moment is that `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction` is not viable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any package beginning with `sun.foo` is [private API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) and likely to change without notice. *Though the way JavaScript is bundled is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089773/javascript-engine-can-not-be-found-scripting-for-the-java-platform/6089959) anyway.*

Still, I would prefer to let the engine do the test:

```
private static boolean isFunction(ScriptEngine engine, String name)
    throws ScriptException {
  String test = "typeof " + name
      + " === 'function' ? java.lang.Boolean.TRUE : java.lang.Boolean.FALSE";
  return (Boolean) engine.eval(test);
}
```

This code guards against the scripting engine returning a script-native boolean type by explicitly returning a `java.lang.Boolean`.