# Java 8, Using Nashorn with Java 8 Compact Profiles

Tags: java-8, nashorn

Is it possible to use [Nashorn (the new JavaScript engine for Java8)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/) together with each of the three Java 8 compact profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Nashorn in all compact profiles.  This is explicitly documented [in the compact profiles for embedded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/compact-profiles.htm) documentation:

> Compact1 Profile APIs
>
> Similar to the legacy Connected Device Configuration (CDC) with the Foundation Profile, secure sockets layer (SSL), logging, and scripting language support, including Javascript. When configured with the minimal JVM, the compact1 profile APIs have a static footprint of about 12MB.

Each compact profile is a superset of the previous one, so by virtue of being usable in compact1, Nashorn is also usable in compact2 and compact3.

As further evidence, bug [JDK-8027532](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027532) was filed and resolved to ensure Nashorn doesn't use any classes outside of compact1.

Note that there is [no requirement for JVMs to provide any particular script engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089773/javascript-engine-can-not-be-found-scripting-for-the-java-platform).  Thus while Nashorn is compatible with all compact profiles, a particular JVM may not make it available.